# Change staff position of hi-hat

Tags: lilypond, engraving, drum-kits

This is what it currently looks like: 
[image: note head on fourth space from bottom] 
This is what I want it to look like: 
[image: note head on space above top staff line]

My code currently looks like this:

```
\version "2.22.2"

\header {
  title = "abc"
}

\drums {
  \clef percussion
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4

  << {
    hh4 4 4 4
  } \\ {
    
  } >>
}
```

Comment: Most seem to put hi-hat above the top line, although others will put cymbal there, and use top line itself for 'charlie' (hi-hat). Unless it's played with the foot, when 'x' is below the bottom line. Agostini seems to be the most used,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LilyPond has few different "styles" that set the positions for the various instruments on a percussion staff.   See [2.51 Common notation for percussion - Percussion staves](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-percussion#percussion-staves).

For example, to change to the "agostini" style, place

```
\set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #agostini-drums-style
```

in the `\new DrumStaff` or `\drums` block.

(LilyPond v2.23 also has a "weinberg" style.)

---

Alternatively, you might like to define your own custom style, such as:

```
#( define my-drum-kit-style
    '(
        ( hihat         cross   #f   5 )
        ( snare         default #f   1 )
        ( bassdrum      default #f  -3 )
        ( crashcymbal   cross   #f   6 )
        ( ridecymbal    cross   #f   4 )
        ( himidtom      default #f   3 )
        ( lowmidtom     default #f   2 )
        ( highfloortom  default #f  -1 )
    )
)
```

This style table can be called with:

```
\set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #(alist->hash-table my-drum-kit-style)
```

Comment: I didn't know that I was still running an old version of lilypond. The weinberg style did it for me in terms of positioning. But now the stems of hihat and bass drum are disconnected: https://i.imgur.com/VHCpJVw.png. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @JonasHardt That should be opened as a separate question.

Comment: @JonasHardt  
That's happening because of the (now slightly larger) space between the notes.  
It's not really about percussion notation though; the same thing happens with notes on a regular staff.  
I'm sure there is a way to fix it, but I haven't figured it out yet.  
It would make a good seperate question.

Comment: @JonasHardt, just combine <bd hh>8. Happy to see another Weinberg user! :D

Answer (score 3):

To do this, redefine the `DrumStaff.drumStyleTable`.

```
\version "2.22.2"

#(define mydrums '(
         (hihat           cross     #f           5)))

\drums {
  \clef percussion
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4

  << {
    \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #(alist->hash-table mydrums)
    hh4 4 4 4
  } \\ {
    
  } >>
}
```

For more, see the LilyPond manual entry on [Custom percussion staves](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-percussion#custom-percussion-staves).