# Force note stems to be connected

Tags: lilypond, drum-kits

After [changing my style to weinberg](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/126528/89845), the hi hat and bass drum stems are now disconnected:

[image: disconnected]

My code:

```
\version "2.24"

\header {
  title = "abc"
}

\drums {
  \clef percussion
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4
  \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #weinberg-drums-style

  << {
    hh4 4 4 4
  } \\ {
    \stemUp
    
    bd8 8 sn4 s sn8 bd8
  } >>
}
```

How can I "force" them to always connect?

Comment: This may be specific to Weinberg. When I run your code in [HackLily](https://www.hacklily.org/) it works fine, but the Weinberg style is ignored.

Comment: HackLily uses lilypond 2.23.2, weinberg was added in 2.24, perhaps that's the cause?

Comment: I'm saying that if you remove Weinberg altogether, the stems work as expected. I don't have a way to test 2.24, but try removing the Weinberg line and see if the stems then behave as you want them.

Comment: Yeah, removing the weinberg style 'fixes' it. @Elements In Space said that it is caused by the larger space between the notes in the weinberg style.

Comment: Try my solution to your other question. An initial test indicates it will align the stems the way you want.

Comment: I suggest you change your example to something that doesn't include weinberg or even a percussion staff because that's just distracting; something like:
`\new Staff { << { g''4 4 4 4 | g''4 4 4 4 | } \\ 
{ \voiceOne f'8 8 4 2 | a'8 8 4 2 | } >> } `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that weinberg style has the hats on the g space instead of the e space, which is by default too far apart to have Lilypond connect the Stems. Solve this by increasing the length of the corresponding stem:

```
\version "2.24"

\header {
  title = "abc"
}

\drums {
  \clef percussion
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4
  \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #weinberg-drums-style

  << {
    hh4 4 4 4
  } \\ {
    \stemUp
    \once\override Stem.length-fraction = #1.5
    bd8 8 sn4 s sn8 bd8
  } >>
}
```

Just keep in mind that this does look a bit weird.